# Run bleak (python library) in background with asyncio

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I want to use the bleak library in Python to receive data from a Bluetooth Low Energy device. This part is working. My problem is now, that I don't know how to run this code in the background or parallel.

Eventually, I want to build a tiny python app which is processing the data from the Bluetooth device. So bleak is looping all the time fetching data from a bluetooth device and sending it to the main process where it is processed and displayed.

For some reason, bleak does not run in a thread. Is it possible to use asyncio for this (since it is already used by bleak maybe a good way to go)?

I checked out threads and multiprocessing but somehow I found only examples without processes which loop infinitely and send data. I'm totally new to the topic of parallelization and/or asynchronous processes. Maybe one of you can give a hint where to look for a proper solution for this case.

Below is my code so far (for now I just loop and print data).

```
from bleak import BleakClient
import json
import time

current_index = 0

time_array = [0] * 20


def TicTocGenerator():
    # Generator that returns time differences
    ti = 0           # initial time
    tf = time.time() # final time
    while True:
        ti = tf
        tf = time.time()
        yield tf-ti # returns the time difference

TicToc = TicTocGenerator() # create an instance of the TicTocGen generator

# This will be the main function through which we define both tic() and toc()
def toc(tempBool=True):
    # Prints the time difference yielded by generator instance TicToc
    tempTimeInterval = next(TicToc)
    global current_index
    if tempBool:
        #print( "Elapsed time: %f seconds.\n" %tempTimeInterval )
        time_array[current_index] = tempTimeInterval
        if current_index == 19:
            current_index = 0
        else:
            current_index += 1


def tic():
    # Records a time in TicToc, marks the beginning of a time interval
    toc(False)


def Average(lst): 
    return sum(lst) / len(lst) 


#address = "30:ae:a4:5d:bc:ba"
address = "CCA9907B-10EA-411E-9816-A5E247DCA0C7"
MODEL_NBR_UUID = "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"



async def run(address, loop):
    async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
        while True: 
            tic()
            model_number = await client.read_gatt_char(MODEL_NBR_UUID)
            toc()
            json_payload=json.loads(model_number)
            print()
            print(json_payload)
            print("Temp    [°C]: "+"{:.2f}".format(json_payload["Temp"]))
            print("Volt     [V]: "+"{:.2f}".format(json_payload["Volt"]))
            print("AngX:         "+str(json_payload["AngX"]))
            print("AngY:         "+str(json_payload["AngY"]))
            print("AngZ:         "+str(json_payload["AngZ"]))
            #print("Millis: {0}".format("".join(map(chr, model_number))))
            print("Average [ms]: {:.1f}".format(Average(time_array)*1000))


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run(address, loop))
```

Comment: Why would you want to "run in a thread"? The whole point of asyncio is to not require threads for IO-bound code where waiting for IO can be efficiently performed by the event loop.

Comment: @user4815162342 I want to have two separate "programs" which run at different speed and independently. The Bluetooth-part should run in a loop all the time but the main program should also be able to perform tasks which may take a little bit longer for example (e.g. a second or so). Maybe you're right and I should have a look at asyncio more closely

Comment: That's what asyncio tasks are for - look into `asyncio.create_task()`. Be aware that in asyncio you're not allowed to call anything that might block. All blocking calls must be async and called using `await`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make GUI for app that automates FUOTA on multiple BLE devices so my solution was to put bleak loop in separate thread in order to be able to use tkinter mainloop in main thread. You need to use asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe to schedule a new task from main thread.

```
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk
from Bleak import BleakScanner

async def scan():
    device = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for device in devices:
        print(device)

def startScan():
    # call startScan() from main thread
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(scan(), loop)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    # ...
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    def bleak_thread(loop):
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_forever()
    t = Thread(target=bleak_thread, args=(loop,))
    t.start()

    window.mainloop()
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)
```