ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrt.windows.foundation.collections'
I have a Tkinter program that uses several libraries (matplotlib, numpy, pygame, …) as well as the bleak BLE library. I create an exe on windows using PyInstaller and most of the program works correctly except when I try to use the bleak library. I am getting exceptions and the traceback mention ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrt.windows.foundation.collections'
I do not know how to fix the problem and would appreciate some help!
Here is an exemple of the messages I receive:
2024-10-23 14:09:21,946 - base_events ERROR - Exception in callback BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...0026A917BBC30>, <winrt._winrt...0026A8DFC4610>)
handle: <Handle BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...0026A917BBC30>, <winrt._winrt...0026A8DFC4610>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run*emphasized text*
  File "bleak\backends\winrt\scanner.py", line 147, in _received_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrt.windows.foundation.collections'

__________________ UPDATE _________________
This is a large program 3500+ lines so I have extracted a simple ble module that reproduce the errors.
from __future__ import annotations
import asyncio
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from bleak import BleakScanner, BleakClient
from bleak.backends.device import BLEDevice
from bleak.backends.service import BleakGATTService, BleakGATTServiceCollection
import bleak.exc
import logging
import copy
import seq, dmutil, dme

# from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
# from bleak.exc import BleakError
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162898/run-bleak-python-library-in-background-with-asyncio
# https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#:~:text=Calling%20asyncio.run()%20more%20than%20once%20Bleak
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858511/using-threads-in-combination-with-asyncio


class Ble:
    DM_DATA_SERVICE_UUID = "36794f20-3a88-418c-8df8-7394c5c80200"
    DM_COMMAND_CHAR_UUID = "36794f20-3a88-418c-8df8-7394c5c80201"
    DM_BRIGHT_CHAR_UUID = "36794f20-3a88-418c-8df8-7394c5c80202"

    def __init__(self, app) -> None:
        def run_asyncio_loop(loop):
            """Run an asyncio loop forever"""
            asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            loop.run_forever()

        # Create and start a thread for the ble asynchronous loop
        self.ble_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=run_asyncio_loop, args=(self.ble_loop,), daemon=True
        )
        asyncio_thread.start()

        self.app: dme.App = app
        self.found_dm = False
        self.device: BLEDevice
        self.client: BleakClient

    async def aio_scan_for_dm(self) -> bool:
        """Scan BLE devices looking for DM. Store device/client info if found"""
        logging.info("Scanning Bluetooth Low Energy for devices ...")
        self.found_dm = False
        devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
        for device in devices:
            logging.info(f"Found device {device.name} at {device.address} ")
            if device.name and (device.name.startswith("DM_")):
                self.found_dm = True
                self.device = device
                self.client = BleakClient(self.device, timeout=5.0)
        return self.found_dm

    async def aio_connect(self) -> bool:
        """Connect to the found DM"""
        logging.info(f"Connecting to {self.name} ...")
        if not self.found_dm:
            await self.aio_scan_for_dm()
        if self.found_dm:
            try:
                await self.client.connect()
                logging.info("Connected ...")
            except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError as e:
                logging.error(f"Can't connect to device {self.device.address} {e}.")
                return False
        else:
            return False
        return True

    async def aio_disconnect(self) -> None:
        """Disconnect from the DM"""
        logging.info(f"Disconnecting from {self.name} ...")
        if self.found_dm and self.client.is_connected:
            await self.client.disconnect()

    async def aio_send_brightness(self, level: int):
        """Set DM brightness level"""
        if not (0 <= level <= 100):
            logging.error(
                "Brightness should be set between 0% and 100%. Setting it to 50%"
            )
            level = 50
        logging.info(f"Changing brithness to {level}%")
        try:
            await self.client.write_gatt_char(
                Ble.DM_BRIGHT_CHAR_UUID, bytes([level]), response=True
            )
        except bleak.exc.BleakError as e:
            logging.error(f"Can't write brightness to {self.device.name} : {e}")

    async def aio_stop_seq(self):
        """Stop the sequence"""
        logging.info(f"Stop display LED")
        try:
            await self.client.write_gatt_char(
                Ble.DM_COMMAND_CHAR_UUID, bytes([0xFF]), response=True
            )
        except bleak.exc.BleakError as e:
            logging.error(f"Can't stop sequence of {self.device.name} : {e}")

    @staticmethod
    def encode_led(leds: list[str]) -> int:
        """Encode the led in an int"""
        led = 0
        if "A1" in leds:
            led += 1
        if "A2" in leds:
            led += 2
        if "A3" in leds:
            led += 4
        if "A4" in leds:
            led += 8
        if "A5" in leds:
            led += 16
        if "B1" in leds:
            led += 32
        if "B2" in leds:
            led += 64
        if "B3" in leds:
            led += 128
        if "B4" in leds:
            led += 256
        if "B5" in leds:
            led += 512
        return led

    @staticmethod
    def encode_oscillator(
        cmd_index: int, osc_index: int, duration: int, oscillator: seq.Oscillator
    ) -> bytearray:
        """Encode one step"""
        data = bytearray()
        data.append(cmd_index)
        data.append(osc_index)
        data.extend(duration.to_bytes(2, byteorder="big"))
        data.extend(Ble.encode_led(oscillator.leds).to_bytes(2, byteorder="big"))
        data.extend(int(oscillator.f_start * 10).to_bytes(2, byteorder="big"))
        data.extend(int(oscillator.f_end * 10).to_bytes(2, byteorder="big"))
        data.append(int(oscillator.d_start))
        data.append(int(oscillator.d_end))
        data.extend(int(oscillator.b_start * 10).to_bytes(2, byteorder="big"))
        data.extend(int(oscillator.b_end * 10).to_bytes(2, byteorder="big"))
        # s = [" ".join(format(x, "02x") for x in data)]
        # logging.info(s)
        return data

    async def aio_send_step(self, step: seq.Step):
        """Send one Step to the DM"""
        logging.info(
            f"Sending the step with index={step.index} osc {len(step.oscillators)} to {self.name}"
        )
        duration = step.t_end - step.t_start
        data: list[bytearray] = []
        data.append(bytearray([1]))  # start command list
        # data.append(bytearray.fromhex("00000001000707d007d0646400320005"))
        # data.append(bytearray.fromhex("01000001006007d007d0646400320005"))
        # data.append(bytearray.fromhex("02000001001807d007d0646400320005"))
        # data.append(bytearray.fromhex("03000001018007d007d0646400320005"))
        # data.append(bytearray.fromhex("04000001000107d007d0646400320005"))

        # append all the oscillators for this step
        for osc_idx, osc in enumerate(step.oscillators):
            data.append(Ble.encode_oscillator(0, osc_idx, duration, osc))

        data.append(bytearray([2]))  # start playing step

        try:
            for cmd in data:
                logging.info(f"{cmd.hex(" ", 2)}")
                await self.client.write_gatt_char(Ble.DM_COMMAND_CHAR_UUID, cmd)
        except bleak.exc.BleakError as e:
            logging.info(f"Can't send data to {self.name}: {e}")

    async def aio_send_seq(self, seq: seq.Sequence):
        """Send one Step to the DM"""
        logging.info(
            f"Sending sequence {seq.name} to {self.name} with {len(seq.steps)} steps length={seq.duration}"
        )
        data: list[bytearray] = []
        data.append(bytearray([1]))  # start command code
        # append all steps
        for step_idx, step in enumerate(seq.steps):
            duration = step.t_end - step.t_start
            # append all the oscillators for this step
            for osc_idx, osc in enumerate(step.oscillators):
                if osc.leds == []:  # if no led used skip
                    continue
                data.append(Ble.encode_oscillator(step_idx, osc_idx, duration, osc))
        data.append(bytearray([2]))  # stop cmd code: start playing step
        # send the sequence to the DM
        try:
            for cmd in data:
                logging.info(f"--- {cmd.hex(" ", 2)}")
                await self.client.write_gatt_char(Ble.DM_COMMAND_CHAR_UUID, cmd)
        except bleak.exc.BleakError as e:
            logging.info(f"Can't send data to {self.name}: {e}")

    async def aio_show_ble_info(self):
        """Show Services, Characteritic, and Descriptor of a connected DM (for debug)"""
        for service in self.client.services:
            logging.info("Services:")
            for service in self.client.services:
                logging.info(f"- Service Description: {service.description}")
                logging.info(f"  UUID: {service.uuid}")
                logging.info(f"  Handle: {service.handle}")
                for char in service.characteristics:
                    value = None
                    if "read" in char.properties:
                        try:
                            value = bytes(await self.client.read_gatt_char(char))
                        except Exception as error:
                            value = error
                    logging.info(f"  - Characteristic Description: {char.description}")
                    logging.info(f"    UUID: {char.uuid}")
                    logging.info(f"    Handle: {char.handle}")
                    logging.info(f"    Properties: {', '.join(char.properties)}")
                    logging.info(f"    Value: {value}")
                    for descriptor in char.descriptors:
                        desc_value = None
                        try:
                            desc_value = bytes(
                                await self.client.read_gatt_descriptor(char.handle)
                            )
                        except Exception as error:
                            desc_value = error
                        logging.info(
                            f"    - Descriptor Description: {descriptor.description}"
                        )
                        logging.info(f"      UUID: {descriptor.uuid}")
                        logging.info(f"      Handle: {descriptor.handle}")
                        logging.info(f"      Value: {desc_value}")

    @property
    def name(self) -> str | None:
        if self.found_dm:
            return self.device.name
        return ""

    @property
    def address(self) -> str | None:
        if self.found_dm:
            return self.device.address
        return ""

    @property
    def is_connected(self) -> bool:
        if self.found_dm:
            return self.client.is_connected
        else:
            return False

    async def aio_play_seq(self, seq) -> None:
        logging.info("Play thread started")
        await self.aio_send_brightness(self.app.param_frame.brightness_var.get())
        await self.aio_send_seq(seq)
        await asyncio.sleep(seq.duration)

    def play_dmled(self, position: float):
        if position == 0.0:  # send original sequence
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
                self.aio_play_seq(self.app.sequence), self.ble_loop
            )
        else:  # we create a new seq that start from position
            cur_step, pos, osc_values = dmutil.step_pos_values_at_time(
                position, self.app.sequence
            )
            actual_step = self.app.sequence.steps[cur_step]
            oscillators = []
            for osc_idx, osc in enumerate(actual_step.oscillators):
                osc.f_start = osc_values[osc_idx][0]
                osc.f_end = actual_step.oscillators[osc_idx].f_end
                osc.b_start = osc_values[osc_idx][1]
                osc.b_end = actual_step.oscillators[osc_idx].b_end
                osc.d_start = osc_values[osc_idx][2]
                osc.d_end = actual_step.oscillators[osc_idx].d_end
                osc.leds = actual_step.oscillators[osc_idx].leds
                oscillators.append(osc)
            duration = actual_step.t_end - actual_step.t_start - pos
            # logging.info(f"{cur_step=} {pos=} {duration=}")
            new_step = seq.Step(actual_step.index, 0, duration, oscillators)
            # logging.info(new_step)
            # create a sequence starting with new_step
            new_seq = seq.Sequence("temp_seq", None, 0, [new_step])
            # now add the following steps
            last_time = duration
            if cur_step != len(self.app.sequence.steps) - 1:
                for step_idx, step in enumerate(
                    self.app.sequence.steps[cur_step + 1 :]
                ):
                    new_seq.steps.insert(step_idx + 1, copy.deepcopy(step))
                    duration = step.t_end - step.t_start
                    new_seq.steps[-1].t_start = last_time
                    new_seq.steps[-1].t_end = last_time + duration
                    new_seq.steps[-1].index = step.index
                    new_seq.steps[-1].oscillators = step.oscillators
                    last_time = new_seq.steps[-1].t_end
                new_seq.duration = new_seq.steps[-1].t_end
            # logging.info(new_seq)
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.aio_play_seq(new_seq), self.ble_loop)

    def stop_dmled(self):
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.aio_stop_seq(), self.ble_loop)


####################### BELOW TEST ###############################
####################### BELOW TEST ###############################
####################### BELOW TEST ###############################


class App(tk.Tk):
    """Test program: scan for dm, connect/disconnect, send sequence"""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.ble = Ble(self)
        self.loop = self.ble.ble_loop

        self.title("Test BLE")
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self._quit)
        logging.basicConfig(
            level=20,
            format="{asctime} - {module} {levelname} - {message}",
            style="{",
            # datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        )
        tk.Button(self, text="Scan DM", width=15, command=self.scan_for_dm).grid(
            row=0, column=0, padx=5, sticky="w"
        )
        self.tb_dm_name = tk.Label(
            self,
            width=30,
            justify="left",
            bg="silver",
            text="Click scan ...",
            anchor="w",
        )
        self.tb_dm_name.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
        self.bt_connect = tk.Button(
            self, text="Connect", width=15, command=self.connect_disconnect
        )
        self.bt_connect.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, sticky="w")
        self.tb_dm_status = tk.Label(
            self, width=30, text="Disconnected", justify="left", anchor="w", bg="silver"
        )
        self.tb_dm_status.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")
        scan_button = tk.Button(self, text="Test DM", width=15, command=self.start_test)
        scan_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, sticky="w")

    def _quit(self) -> None:
        self.quit()
        self.destroy()

    def scan_for_dm(self):
        # Submit the scan task to the asyncio loop and set up a callback
        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.ble.aio_scan_for_dm(), self.loop)
        future.add_done_callback(lambda f: self.update_dm_name())

    def connect_disconnect(self):
        if not self.ble.is_connected:
            self.tb_dm_status.configure(text=f"Connecting...")
            future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.ble.aio_connect(), self.loop)
        else:
            self.tb_dm_status.configure(text=f"Disonnecting...")
            future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
                self.ble.aio_disconnect(), self.loop
            )
        future.add_done_callback(lambda f: self.update_dm_status())
        future.add_done_callback(lambda f: self.update_dm_name())

    def start_test(self):
        logging.info("calling test_dm in a thread")
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.test_dm(), self.loop)

    def update_dm_name(self):
        # Update the text with detected devices
        if self.ble.found_dm:
            self.tb_dm_name.configure(
                text=f"{self.ble.name} ({self.ble.address})",
                justify="left",
            )
        else:
            self.tb_dm_name.configure(text="No DM found", justify="left")

    def update_dm_status(self):
        # Update the text with connection status
        if self.ble.is_connected:
            self.tb_dm_status.configure(text=f"Connected")
            self.bt_connect.configure(text="Disconnect")
        else:
            self.tb_dm_status.configure(text=f"Disconnected")
            self.bt_connect.configure(text="Connect", justify="left")

    async def test_dm(self) -> None:
        osc1 = seq.Oscillator(["A1", "A4", "B1"], 9, 10, 50, 50, 80, 10)
        osc2 = seq.Oscillator(["A1", "A5", "B2"], 8, 9, 30, 30, 10, 80)
        step1 = seq.Step(0, 0, 10, [osc1, osc2])
        step2 = seq.Step(0, 0, 5, [osc2, osc1])
        if not self.ble.is_connected:
            await self.ble.aio_connect()
        await self.ble.aio_send_brightness(50)
        await self.ble.aio_send_step(step1)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        logging.info("changing brightness at middle of step")
        await self.ble.aio_send_brightness(20)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        logging.info("second step")
        await self.ble.aio_send_brightness(50)
        await self.ble.aio_send_step(step2)
        # create seq
        logging.info("Creating and sending sequence")
        new_seq = seq.Sequence("Test", None, 15, [step1, step2])
        await self.ble.aio_send_seq(new_seq)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()  # build initial display
    app.mainloop()  # process tkinter events

to reproduce the error use
pyinstaller ble.py
the run the program generated
here is the beginning of the log file produced when running
2024-10-25 14:10:31,659 - ble INFO - Scanning Bluetooth Low Energy for devices ...
2024-10-25 14:10:32,744 - base_events ERROR - Exception in callback BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13570>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A13430>)
handle: <Handle BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13570>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A13430>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
  File "bleak\backends\winrt\scanner.py", line 147, in _received_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrt.windows.foundation.collections'
2024-10-25 14:10:32,746 - base_events ERROR - Exception in callback BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13DB0>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A127D0>)
handle: <Handle BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13DB0>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A127D0>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
  File "bleak\backends\winrt\scanner.py", line 147, in _received_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrt.windows.foundation.collections'
2024-10-25 14:10:33,026 - base_events ERROR - Exception in callback BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13D90>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A12750>)
handle: <Handle BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13D90>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A12750>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
  File "bleak\backends\winrt\scanner.py", line 147, in _received_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrt.windows.foundation.collections'
2024-10-25 14:10:33,030 - base_events ERROR - Exception in callback BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13E30>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A13EB0>)
handle: <Handle BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13E30>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A13EB0>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
  File "bleak\backends\winrt\scanner.py", line 147, in _received_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrt.windows.foundation.collections'
2024-10-25 14:10:33,990 - base_events ERROR - Exception in callback BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13D10>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A13DD0>)
handle: <Handle BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13D10>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A13DD0>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
  File "bleak\backends\winrt\scanner.py", line 147, in _received_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrt.windows.foundation.collections'
2024-10-25 14:10:33,993 - base_events ERROR - Exception in callback BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13C90>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A13E70>)
handle: <Handle BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13C90>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A13E70>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
  File "bleak\backends\winrt\scanner.py", line 147, in _received_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrt.windows.foundation.collections'
2024-10-25 14:10:34,307 - base_events ERROR - Exception in callback BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13C10>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A13CF0>)
handle: <Handle BleakScannerWinRT._received_handler(<winrt._winrt...001EF94A13C10>, <winrt._winrt...001EF94A13CF0>)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio\events.py", line 88, in _run
  File "bleak\backends\winrt\scanner.py", line 147, in _received_handler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrt.windows.foundation.collections'


Please share your complete code and error traceback.

I have added a small piece of the code that is enough to reproduce the problem as well as the output. FYI I have the winrt.windows.foundation.collections package installed

you install the winrt?
pip install winrt

Check if the virtual enviroment is correct and active!

pip install winrt returns no matching distribution ....
Also why would I need to add something? pyinstaller has created an _internal directory that is supposed to contain all the required lib ???

After many research I found the solution that I post here in case somebody encounter the same problem.
The problem is that Winrt is dead and not maintained anymore by Microsoft!
What help me in finding the solution was the following post
Basically, WinRT has been replaced by PyWinRT
So, you need to install:
pip install winrt-Windows.Devices.Bluetooth winrt-Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement winrt-Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile winrt-Windows.Devices.Enumeration winrt-Windows.Foundation winrt-Windows.Foundation.Collections

I think most can be installed using
pip install bleak-winrt

But still pyinstaller fails to build a running executable.
What you need to do is run pyinstaller like this
pyinstaller --hidden-import winrt.windows.foundation.collections ble.py

Et voilà this solves the problem 
